# How to select an item by attribute without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I need select element like this: `$('[data-key=' + objectId + ']')`, but i need select this without jquery, using `document.querySelector` or something else on pure JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `document.querySelectorAll('[data-key=' + objectId + ']')` and loop through all results

```
var allKeys = document.querySelectorAll('[data-key=' + objectId + ']');

[].forEach.call(allKeys, function(elem){
   console.log(elem); //Do your stuff with each element
});
```

Comment: @BenilMathew Thanks :)

Comment: But, `'[data-key=' + objectId + ']'` not valid selector :\

Comment: I don't know: [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/6ce135e383cb73a7797de0701cf61a15.png)

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @skriming Attribute values must start with a strings. you can put a prefix letter before attribute value

Comment: @VickyGonsalves oh... thanks, but i can't add prefix for attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<p data-test="testquery">

document.querySelectorAll('[data-test]')
```